# Extending application's model in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

I have an application which defines some models. I want to extend the functionality of some models(eg. adding methods,adding associations) from application to my engine. 
I tried adding a model in the engine with the same name as my application's model and Rails will automatically merge them, however it doesn't work.

eg: 
(Application's model)

```
class Article < ActiveRecord:Base 
 def from_application
    puts "application"
 end
end

(Inside my Engine)
module MyEngine
  class Article < ::Article
    has_many :metrics, :class_name => 'Metric'
  end 
end
```

has_many association is not getting applied to my Articles model when I try to access @articles.metrics. Any ideas ?

Comment: I think class_eval is what you are looking for. I have no experience with it, but read this recently: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers

Comment: @Arun Kumar M  ,  do you have your metrics model have a belongs_to association with Articles. How does your migration looks like and does your Metric table hold the article_id. What is the exact error message you get?

Comment: @OlalekanSogunle Yes I do! I double checked it :)

Comment: @siax: Checked that link. But it doesn't apply associations

Comment: Can you add the exact error message you get?

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea and are close. But your implementation is a little off.

Generally, your engine should have **no** knowledge of your host app. That way, your engine and the host app(s) stay loosely coupled. So, classes in your engine should **not** inherit from classes in your host app. (BTW, your approach doesn't work, I believe, because of the way ruby does constant lookups, but that's a different discussion.)

Instead, use the [included hook](http://www.sitepoint.com/hitchhikers-guide-to-metaprogramming-classmodule-hooks/). In the host app, you do something like:

```
  class Article < ActiveRecord:Base 
    include FooEngine::BarModule

    def from_application
      puts "application"
    end

  end
```

And inside the engine:

```
  module FooEngine
    module BarModule
      def self.included(base)
        base.class_eval do 
          has_many :metrics, :class_name => 'Metric'
        end
      end
    end 
  end
```

When the ruby interpreter goes to include `FooEngine::BarModule` in `Article`, it will look for and run (if found) the `self.included` method in `FooEngine::BarModule`, passing in the `Article`class as `base`.

You then call `class_eval` on the `base` (`Article`) which re-opens the `Article` class so that you can add methods or whatever monkey business you're up to (define new methods *in situ*, include or extend other modules, etc.).

In your example, you call the `has_many` method, which will create the various association methods provided by `has_many`.

If (a) you're going to add a lot of metrics-related functionality through your engine, (b) you want to have lots of classes make use of the metrics-related functionality, and (c) you want some of the functionality to vary from class-to-class (where included), you might consider creating an `acts_as_having_metrics` (or similar). Once you head down this path, it's a whole new world of wondrous metaprogramming.

Best of luck.

Comment: So if you install FooEngine later you have to go back into every model (such as Article) and add "include FooEngine::BarModule" ? That seems a bit strange. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your metrics model have a belongs_to association with Articles.

You might want to give the other side of the association, Metrics a belongs_to Articles to have this work properly. Also, make sure to have a migration to hold articles_id on the metrics table. Everything should work fine.

Comment: Yes I do! I have the association